# Kinect: AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, kinect, access-violation

We are using the Kinect to stream a customizable video of a user that lets you choose, without stopping the stream, the stream type (color, depth, both with the option to show the tracked skeleton).

Our program runs fine if we change the stream type, but after a few frames (and only on some PCs) of skeleton enabled, the application crashes showing:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException.
```

Here is our code:

```
private void KinectAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())        
    {
        currentSkeleton = GetSkeletonFromSkeletonFrame(skeletonFrame);

        if (this.frameMode == Constants.VIDEO_DEPTH_MODE)
            currentFrame = GetByteArrayFromDepthFrame(e);
        else if (this.frameMode == Constants.VIDEO_COLOR_MODE)
            currentFrame = GetByteArrayFromColorFrame(e);
        else if (this.frameMode == Constants.VIDEO_NONE_MODE)
            currentFrame = GetByteFromBlankFrame();


        if (isSkeleton)
        {
            currentFrame = OverlapSkeleton(currentFrame, this.currentSkeleton);
        }
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private byte[] OverlapSkeleton(byte[] currentFrame, Skeleton S)
{
    Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH, Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_HEIGHT, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    BitmapData tempBmapData = tempBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH, Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_HEIGHT), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, tempBitmap.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = tempBmapData.Scan0;

    for (int i = 0, offset = 0; i < Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(currentFrame, offset, ptr, Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH << 2);
        offset += Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH << 2;
        ptr += tempBmapData.Stride;
    }

    tempBitmap.UnlockBits(tempBmapData);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);

    //  Upper Body
    DrawBone(JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter, S, g);
    //  Left Arm
    DrawBone(JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft, S, g);
    //  Right Arm
    DrawBone(JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight, S, g);
    //  Left leg
    DrawBone(JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft, S, g);
    //  Right Leg
    DrawBone(JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, S, g);
    DrawBone(JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight, S, g);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[Constants.KINECT_COLOR_FRAME_SIZE];
    Marshal.Copy(tempBmapData.Scan0, bytes, 0, Constants.KINECT_COLOR_FRAME_SIZE);

    return bytes;
}

Constants.KINECT_COLOR_FRAME_SIZE = 1228800;
Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH = 640;
Constants.KINECT_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_HEIGHT = 480;
```

The exception is thrown at the line of Marshal.Copy().
We already seen here on SO that somebody suggests not to copy the whole block of data at once, but instead loop and copy every single row of the image (see for loop in OverlapSkeleton), but it doesn't work.

What's weird is that on our developing machines (i5-2410m@2.30GHz/4Gb RAM and i5-m560@2.67GHz/4Gb RAM) it's all working fine, but on the machines which will host the application (i3-2377m@1.5GHz/4Gb RAM) it crashes after 2-3 secs after the skeleton is enabled, throwing that exception.

OS is Win7 SP1, .NET Framework 4.5 for every machine.

Any idea about what would cause this appearently random exception?

Comment: When your program crashes (Marshal.Copy), what is the content of currentFrame, offset and ptr?

Comment: And one more question: is there any particular reason you're using AggressiveInlining for?

Comment: The last values for offset is 1228800, ptr is 536002560.
The exception is thrown when i (the frame row) is 479

We use AffessiveInlining just to get a little performance increase, but we already tried to remove it and nothing changed

The currentFrame is full of values representing the current frame bytes
(I'm in the same team of breathe0)

Comment: When your program crashes, how big (length-wise) is your *currentFrame*? Is the size consistent? How does it relate to the value of *tempBmapData.Stride* x *tempBitmap.Height*?

Comment: tempBmapData.Stride is 2560, tempBitmap.Height is 480, the product is effectively 1228800. surprisingly adding a console.writeline() to print these values for each iteration in the for loop slows down the computation, but this time the application does not crash. do you think it's related in a certain way?

Comment: UPDATE: we tried a couple of times, and it crashes but we noticed that the crash occours after several seconds, and it always happens at the first iteration of the for loop (where i is equal to 479, logging it after the Marshal.Copy(), so it seems that it succeed to complete the whole frame but it fails to start the following one)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell yet. What is the length of your *currentFrame* when the application crashes?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same PixelFormat in your *currentFrame*? *tempBitmap* is 32bpp (4Bpp), but it looks like *currentFrame* is only 8bpp (1Bpp) since its length is 1228800. Could you check that?

Comment: yes: our image is 640x480x4Bpp, which is 1228800 bytes. why are you  supposing that currentframe is only 1Bpp?

Comment: My mistake, I misread your comment and thought that *2560* is your width, not the stride. In this case, since your array is really only 1228800 bytes long, you can't use this value as an offset as it's out of the array's range. You can only index it from 0 to 1228799.

Comment: of course, but the last value printed is after the Marshal.Copy() executes, not before. So when at the beginning of the loop i is equal to 480 and the offset is 1228800, the cycle body is not executed. The point here is that this error does not happen on the first frame nor on a specific one, it's kinda random

Comment: What is the value of *Constants.KINECT_COLOR_FRAME_SIZE*?

Comment: I'm afraid I've run out of ideas. I'll give it some more thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real solution, but more a hack / workarond.

Anyway I found that the exception is throwed randomly, but not frequently, so the workaround is to decorate the OverlapSkeleton method with

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
```

and

```
[SecurityCritical]
```

Doing this it is possible to catch CSEs using a try/catch. The resulting code is:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
private byte[] OverlapSkeleton(byte[] currentFrame, Skeleton S)
{
    if (S == null)
        return currentFrame;

    try
    {
        //The above code with Marshall.copy and lines drawing
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return currentFrame;
    }
```

Again, it doesn't solve the problem, but since there's no performance impact and we also runned out of ideas this is the best solution I have to offer. If anyone  has a better/working idea is welcomed.